# identificar dispositivos criados via v4l2loopback no chrome

Tags: google-chrome, electron, webrtc, chromium

No programa v4l2loopback, o parametro **card_label**, coloca um rotulo em cada câmera criada, e isso é identificado no Chrome/Chromium, conforme imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas a saída do comando javascript de listar dispositivos, não mostra essa informação, eu esperava que estivesse em **label**, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem outra forma de identificar o dispositivo correto?

Update:

No firefox, também não listou os nomes em "label", por isso acreditei ser um comportamento padrão dos navegadores.

Mas depois, testando no Electron, onde pretendo utilizar isso de fato, funciona corretamente... O proccesso "Renderer" dele não deveria ser equivalente ao browser?

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a razão, é por causa do comportamento padrão do Electron, onde tudo que não é expressamente proibido, é permitido, no navegador o rótulo é exibido somente depois de aceitar qual dispositivo será usado para capturar a mídia.
E a call 'enumerateDevices()' não dispara a rotina para selecionar os dispositivos